# SSD RAID in Haswell NUC with Ubuntu: Does TRIM work?

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, raid

I want a low-power, small, silent x86_64 Ubuntu computer with storage that's resilient against hardware failure of a drive.

I'm thinking of buying D54250WYKH or D34010WYKH, one mSATA SSD and one 2.5" SSD of the same capacity.

With Ubuntu 14.04, can I set up encrypted mirroring RAID across the mSATA drive and the 2.5" drive? Will TRIM work in that case? Will the answer to the TRIM question depend on whether it is some kind of Intel firmware RAID (is that available across mSATA and the 2.5" slot on NUCs?) or an Ubuntu/LVM software setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer kernels support software raid (MDRAID) TRIM passtrough.I think Ubuntu 14.04 kernel is fine.
Do not use Intel firmware raid, it's a fake raid.(worse than software raid)

You can check if a block device supports TRIM by issuing `lsblk -D /dev/xxx` where xxx is your block device

Do not forget to enable AHCI in BIOS

Also you must enable TRIM support in your chosen encryption, for example in LUKS `allow-discards` and if you use LVM then also `issue_discards = 1`